# Command for "cmd" to update all the software in windows?

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe

In Ubuntu `sudo apt-get update` update all packages.

Like Ubuntu, does Windows also have any command for cmd to update all installed software in Windows?

Comment: All the software? No,only windows apps installed from the Microsoft store.

Comment: @Moab If I want to update my media player, chrome browser, etc. software from cmd. What command should I give in cmd

Comment: There is no command, third party apps cannot be updated using Windows command, they have to be done manually, a pain I know. Chrome Browser updates automatically as it is built into the product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows system files, Microsoft Store apps and, optionally, Microsoft products are updated through the *Windows Update* control panel application, though this does not have the power of the Debian [Advanced Package Tool](https://www.tecmint.com/apt-advanced-package-command-examples-in-ubuntu/) (apt) to update all added PPA's. You can open the *Windows Update* CPL from the CMD prompt (terminal, for Linux users) to find and to automatically install updates:

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type `cmd`, press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> and click `Yes` in the UAC dialog to get CMD running as Administrator.
- Enter `start ms-settings:windowsupdate-action` to cause the CPL application to fetch the latest updates.

You can also put this script into a batch (shell script) file (e.g. *update.bat*), but you might need to run it as Administrator

At one time, MS provided the application *wuauclt.exe* in the \System32\ folder to enable manual update from CMD, but apparently [that application no longer works](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/wuaucltexe-detectnow-command-doesnt-work-in/43dc5e35-6efa-432e-8256-d30096678849?auth=1). It is possible [to call the *Windows Update Agent* programmatically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387102(v=vs.85).aspx), but the code MS provides in that VB example is **120 lines long**, a far cry from `sudo apt-get update`. There are also examples to [perform that task through MS *PowerShell*](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/jamesone/2009/01/27/managing-windows-update-with-powershell/), though some examples require [installing untrusted modules](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/2d191bcd-3308-4edd-9de2-88dff796b0bc) in *PowerShell*.

Comment: CMD is not running as Administrator by pressing **Shift + Ctrl + Enter**. My question is for software update not for windows update and windows is also updating by opening the GUI. I was asking for cmd command which directly updates without opening any GUI.

Comment: No, Ctrl-Shift-Enter *from the start menu* really does start most commands as admin.

Comment: MS updates only *its own* software, e.g. Edge and installed versions of MS Office. Each non-MS application *may* have its own updater, but there is no equivalent to APT.

Answer (score 3):

You can install [some] software using the 3rd-party equivalent of `apt` in Ubuntu/Linux or `brew` in macOS - [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org) and [Scoop](https://scoop.sh), both of which allow the upgrading of software installed via *those* package managers.

- Chocolatey:

  ```
  choco upgrade all -y
  ```
- Scoop:

  ```
  scoop upgrade
  ```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to archieve that:

- Script it using the [Windows Update PowerShell Module](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/2d191bcd-3308-4edd-9de2-88dff796b0bc)
- Commercial tools built for that purpose for professionals, such as:

  - [WuInstall](http://www.wuinstall.com): purely command-line based like `apt-get`
  - [BatchPatch](http://www.batchpatch.com): provides a GUI

Both work fine, but the first is probably better if you want to do it purely via command-line; however, keep in mind, unlike `apt-get update`, only MS-software can be updated this way -  there is no centralized package manager for all Windows software.

Answer (score 2):

The following is the best method for installing updates for all apps in Windows:
Run CMD as administrator.
Type:

> winget upgrade --all
> winget upgrade --ignore-unknown

Answer (score 1):

It’s 2022! Things have changed. We now have the [Windows Package Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Package_Manager) (winget), which is the next best thing. It still isn’t *apt-get* though. Operating system updates are still exclusively distributed using Windows Update.

In contrast to all the other existing solutions (like Chocolatey or whatever), *winget* plays nice with manually installed software! So if you installed, say, Azure CLI in the past, *winget* will detect that and you can update or remove it using *winget*.

*winget* is bundled with Windows nowadays. It’s the mysterious [“App Installer”](https://www.microsoft.com/p/app-installer/9nblggh4nns1#activetab=pivot:overviewtab) program you may have seen when managing installed software.

This all sounds too good to be true? Well, it is. The *winget* feed only has a limited amount of software. So you won’t be able to update everything you have installed. Then there’s problems with localized versions of programs, which are mostly not differentiated and might be updated to a different language version. Furthermore, for some programs, the version currently installed is not determined correctly, leading to endless update cycles.

Do give it a whirl and make sure to report any issues you may see to the appropriate bug trackers.

---

Managing all system components (including stuff like the kernel) using a package manager is only possible if the system has been designed to work like that from the ground up. Windows isn’t. That’s why an all-encompassing package manager will most likely never exist for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Windows updates are installable with `wuauclt.exe /resetauthorization /detectnow /updatenow` command.

If 'Windows Update'->'Advanced Options' has 'Receive updates for other Microsoft products' option on then it must update other Microsoft products as well.