# Can I update installed programs on Windows 10 from command prompt?

Tags: microsoft-office

Can I update programs i have installed on Windows 10 from command prompt?

Example Office 365?

Like in Linux, from terminal: `sudo apt-get update & sudo apt-get upgrade`?

Comment: For c2r versions Office, such as Office 365, Office 2019, please try the command, `"C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\ClickToRun\officec2rclient.exe" /update user updatetoversion=16.0.14131.20332`

The update version could be found from the articles "[Update history for Microsoft 365 Apps (listed by date)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-microsoft365-apps-by-date)",  "[Retail versions of Office 2016 C2R and Office 2019](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-office-2019#retail-versions-of-office-2016-c2r-and-office-2019)".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Command for "cmd" to update all the software in windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/1332107/command-for-cmd-to-update-all-the-software-in-windows)

Comment: When 'Windows Update'->'Advanced Options' has 'Receive updates for other Microsoft products' option set, `wuauclt.exe /resetauthorization /detectnow /updatenow` updates Microsoft office and other Microsoft products altogether with OS components update.

Answer (score 1):

It depends entirely on the App and how it works. Office 365 updates install automatically and there is nothing to do.  Adobe works the same way.

It is always easier to do nothing than trying to update either by GUI or by command line.

Many of my smaller apps require me to update by clicking on something like Help, Update.

If the case of Office, however, there is also the option to update by command line.

[Update Office by command](https://www.clearconcepts.ca/insights/understanding-office-365-updates-and-channelshttps://)

> Launch a Command Prompt as an Administrator. To implement the change
> and start the Channel switch process, run “OfficeC2RClient.exe /update
> user” from the same path. This will initiate office updates download
> based on the channel you are switching to.

Other apps do not always have this option.

So there is no universal way and you are largely  at the mercy of the App you are looking at .

Even in Linux, GIMP did not update by apt-get update. I had to do it manually (Help, Udpate or something like that.